# Categorize difference between max and min value for features with same attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, symbology

I have a points layer. Some points have the same value in FIELD_1. I want to give different colors (value in FIELD_3) for different sizes of ranges of values in field FIELD_2 among points with same FIELD_1.

I'll try to be clearer with an example:

If points have same FIELD_1 and FIELD_2 ranging from 3 (min value) to 10 (max value) return (in FIELD_3) 10-3 = **7**

If points have same FIELD_1 and FIELD_2 ranging from 2 (min value) to 24 (max value) return (in FIELD_3) 24-2 = **22**

etc...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this I would use Summary Statistics on FIELD_2 using FIELD_1 as your case field - that way you get the MIN and MAX for each.

Then Add a Field to its output table that you calculate equal to the difference.

You will then be able to use Join Field to join the difference values back onto your original table.

Comment: I guess FIELD_1 must not be string, right?

Comment: @MicheleCordini FIELD_1 looks like an integer field, and without testing, I am guessing that will cause no problem as a case field.